# control flow and promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have a lot of divs in the html. Each div contains animation or some js code which is call only for this div when it visible:

```
<button id='start' class='start'>Start</button> 

<div class="step1 later">
  <div class='red later'>Show first</div>
  <div class='aqua later'>Show later</div>
</div>

<div class="step2 later">
  <div class='green later'>Show together</div>
  <div class='yellow later'>Show together</div>
</div>
```

My goal is show `div` with `step1` class and call some `js`, then show `step2` and so on. It looks like slider. For this example I want show `step1` and then show `div` with `red` class, after delay I want to show `aqua`. Next, we go to `step2` and show two divs: `yellow`, `green` without delay. I have decided to use promises (Q.js) for this. This is my code:

```
$(function () {
  var currentStep = 1,
      handlers = {};  

  $('#start').click(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {          
      showStep(currentStep + i);
    }     
  });      

  function showStep(step) {
    var name = 'step' + step;
    $('.' + name).show();

    handlers[name]();
  }


  handlers.step1 = function() {
    Q().then(function() {
       $('.notification').html('Step1 started');
    })
    .delay(2000)
    .then(function() {
       showElem('red');     
    })
    .delay(2000)
    .then(function() {
       showElem('aqua');     
    });
  };

    handlers.step2 = function() {
    Q().then(function() {
       $('.notification').append('Step2 started');
    })
    .delay(2000)
    .then(function() {
       showElem('green'); 
       showElem('yellow'); 
    });    
  };

  function showElem(classSelector) {
    $('.' + classSelector).fadeIn(100);
  }

});
```

All animations and delay works find except one thing. My code doesn't wait when one step will finish, handlers start almost at the same time.
DEMO : [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hujoxazoru/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsbin.com/qibuvorayu/1/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather unconventional to use Q to schedule jQuery actions.  With judicious use of its [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) methods, jQuery is well capable of doing this job reliably - on its own.

In the following rewrite of the code :

- promises are returned from various functions to allow chaining
- the master (start) routine is a simple two-step `.then()` chain
- `showElem()` and `showStep()` are unnecessary and disappear
- `handlers` is written as an object literal.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var handlers = {
        'step1': function() {
            $('.notification').html('<div>Step1 started</div>');
            return $(".step1").show(0).delay(2000).promise().then(function() {
                return $('.red').fadeIn(100).delay(2000).promise();
            }).then(function() {
                return $('.aqua').fadeIn(100).promise();
            });
        },
        'step2': function() {
            $('.notification').append('<div>Step2 started</div>');
            return $(".step2").show(0).delay(2000).promise().then(function() {
                return $('.green, .yellow').fadeIn(100);
            });
        }
    };

    $('#start').click(function() {
        handlers.step1().then(handlers.step2);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d7pemmjc/)**

**EDIT**

For a large number of handlers, you could longhand out the "start" routine as follows :

```
$('#start').click(function() {
    handlers.step1()
    .then(handlers.step2)
    .then(handlers.step3)
    .then(handlers.step4)
    .then(handlers.step5)
    .then(handlers.step6)
    ...
    ;
});
```

However, that could be a lot of typing and won't cater for a variable number of handlers.

The solution is reasonably simple.

First, write `handlers` as an Array, instead of Object.

```
var handlers = [
    //step 0
    function() {
        $('.notification').html('<div>Step1 started</div>');
        return $(".step1").show(0).delay(2000).promise().then(function() {
            return $('.red').fadeIn(100).delay(2000).promise();
        }).then(function() {
            return $('.aqua').fadeIn(100).promise();
        });
    },
    //step 1
    function() {
        $('.notification').append('<div>Step2 started</div>');
        return $(".step2").show(0).delay(2000).promise().then(function() {
            return $('.green, .yellow').fadeIn(100);
        });
    },
    //step 2,
    ...
    //step 3,
    ...
];
```

Now, you can use Array method `.reduce()` to scan the array, building a promise chain as it goes :

```
$('#start').click(function() {
    handlers.reduce(function(promise, handler) {
        return promise.then(handler);
    }, $.when());
});
```

Here, `$.when()` is a resolved "seed" promise that gets the chain started.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d7pemmjc/1/)**

Comment: I use jQuery just for example. In real project I don't want to use jQuery. I want to use `velocity.js` or `move.js` for animation and other for DOM manipulation/selector engine. I think I had to write about it.

Comment: Also, in the real project, there will be about 20-50 handlers.

Comment: I don't know `velocity.js` or `move.js`. If their animations don't support promises like jQuery, you might like to consider promisifying them at a low level to give chainability at the higher level.

Comment: Your 20-50 handlers may have repeated patterns to them. If so, then you may be able to write a smaller number of *generic* handlers, which can be control by passing parameters.

Comment: I have added something that should help with a large number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in your initial "for" loop, where you execute all your "showStep" in a go, without waiting for promises.

You could do something like that instead:

```
$('#start').click(function() {
  showStep(1);
});

function showStep(step) {
  var name = 'step' + step;
  $('.' + name).show();
  handlers[name]().then(function() {
    if (step < 2) {
      showStep(step+1);
    }
  });
}
```

And make you handlers return the promise.

Comment: It's usually good form to `return` the promise in case `showStep()` needs to be chained with other things. You also need to `return showStep(step+1)` internally.